# How to use Distinct in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Using SQL I have

```
| Message_From | Message_To  |Message| Message_Time(Current TimeStamp)|
| -------------| ------------|------ | -------------------------------|
| abc@gmail.com|pof@gmail.com| Abc   |2022-04-22 12:26:13             |
| abc@gmail.com|gof@gmail.com| DEF   |2022-04-22 12:26:31             |
| abc@gmail.com|gof@gmail.com| CED   |2022-04-22 12:26:51             |
```

I want to be show as

```
| Message_From | Message_To  | Message_Time(Current TimeStamp)|
| -------------| ------------|-------------------             |
| abc@gmail.com|pof@gmail.com|2022-04-22 12:26:13             |
| abc@gmail.com|gof@gmail.com|2022-04-22 12:26:51             |
```

I want to select the distinct Message_To With the the last Message sent.

I have written a query but its not working as my query is showing all the 3 peoples because the Message time stamp is different

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Message_From], [Message_To] 
FROM 
    [messages] 
WHERE 
    [Message_From] = '$Email'
```

Any idea for this?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server; what RDBMS are you *really* using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: It looks to me like the OP intends to get the latest line for a given `message_to` column value.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question. I’ve locked the post for a while, to make it explicit that we take content integrity serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Message_From, Message_To
                                 ORDER BY Message_Time DESC) rn
    FROM messages
)

SELECT Message_From, Message_To, Message, Message_Tim
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: This may go a bit extreme , but If by chance for a given Message_To value we have two rows with identical  message_time, how can we determine the latest ?  Would it be decided by MySQL 's INSERT SEQUENCE ? If so, should we add an auto increment ID column to mark the sequence of INSERT?

Comment: @blabla_bingo In that case, you would need to add another sorting level to the `ORDER BY` clause in `ROW_NUMBER` to break the tie.

Comment: Do you think it's worth adding an AI column and an addtional layer in the ORDER BY clause for the sake or high precision? Personally, I think it's too redundant to do so : )